# Check if _id existed in any point in time in mongodb(atlas)?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

Is there a way in mongodb (atlas) to find out if a document with an
ObjectId (or different criteria) existed in any point in time for a collection?

For example:

```
db.users.existed({_id: ObjectId("s3dj4834885333")}) = true | false
```

Comment: At _any_ point in time, even if it was deleted long ago? And checking directly using built-in functionality in the database/collection?

Comment: Yes I just want to know if it was created in the database, because my application logs logically proove it must have been created but wasn't.

The point is, I want to find out if something is wrong with my application code that I can not see, or if something db related happened.

Comment: I truly do not mean this as bluntly as it might come across but: application logs will only report what they are told to report. Without (a lot) more information we can't say if that logging the intended events appropriately or if database persistence (e.g. write concern) is configured correctly. The `oplog` would definitively have associated `insert` statements and, apart from auditing, would be your best bet at finding such information. But it is a capped collection so the event may have been overwritten by this point.

Comment: Thank you for those hints ! Will look into it.